# Dynamically storing values in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to dynamically create a `variable` or `table` in SQL which will store distinct values as a result for another `sql` query.

```
declare sample_table table
( values varchar(100))

insert into @sample_table values (select t1.value from my_tablw as t1 group by t1.value);
```

Supposing the `distinct` values in column `value` can change from table query to another table query, I want to store the result of this query in a user defined variable/table which can be used later in another query.

Comment: you cannot do it with variables. Use temp table instead

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?   Why have you tagged `mysql-variables`?   Are you using a MySQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your definition of *can be used later* you can use a local temp table or table variable.... you just need to change the syntax a bit to not use the `values` since you are inserting from the results of a query. I also used `DISTINCT` below which is clearer than the `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function.

```
declare sample_table table ([values] varchar(100))

insert into @sample_table 
select distinct t1.value 
from my_tablw as t1 

--one way to use it
select *
from newTable 
where columnVal in (select * from @sample_table)

--another way to use it
select at.* 
from anotherTable at
inner join @sample_table t on
t.column = at.column

--and another way...
select f.*
from finalTable f
where exists (select * from @sample_table t where t.column = f.column)
```

If you need this to be used outside the scope of your current batch, you'll need to use a persisted table or [global temporary table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4031/sql-server-global-temporary-table-visibility/).

Comment: thank you for the help. A question for you; I was told the `distinct` feature in sql is less "efficient" than `group by` so I haven't been using the former much.

Comment: You would be correct @Josh and [Aaron has a good blog on this](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/01/t-sql-queries/surprises-assumptions-group-by-distinct), I just tend to not go this route unless i need the performance boost. Just personal preference.